# How to do incremental backup in MySQL using LSN using ansible without using percona?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-s3, ansible, mysql-backup

I wants to backup mysql DB incrementally using ansible/shell commands. Can anyone give me the steps involve in it. 
  I have a database and table in my MySQL. my.cnf file having the configuration for that. Every one hour I wants to do the backup and upload my DB datas to the s3 bucket.

Comment: Your question belongs to serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Without using LSN value we can achieve the solution.

- `Flush binary logs` [new binary log file created]
- By using `binlog.index` file, found previous binary file. Copied that
  file to where I want to upload. That is the dump file and I got data
  from that file got restore.
- File saved by current timestamp name value.
- Automation sheduling done by using `crontab -e` file.
- `1 */1 * * *` is the value used for time scheduling.[every first
  minute of an hour]